# express-session change session-varaibles of any user chosen by id

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, cookies, express-session

I'm trying to figure out how to change any user's session varaibles in express-session. I can change the current user's varaibles by simply using `req.session.VARAIBLE_NAME`, but I couldn't find how to interfere any user's session. Is there a way that I could select users by id varaible in their session and interfere the session? Thanks :)

Comment: Why would you like to do that? A request from the client have to be made to alter session.

Comment: express-session only works off the encrypted cookie that represents the key to the session itself and it looks that up in the session data store (whichever kind you're using).  If you want access to the data directly from the data store outside of a request from a specific user, then you will have to be able to query the data store itself, get the data from the store, modify it and write it back.  If you're using a real data store (like mongodb or mysql or any of the other real databases that can be used with express-session), then you can query the database directly to update the data.

Comment: It probably makes more sense that you have your own database entry for each user that is keyed by the user and keep the data you're talking about in the database that way (not directly in the session).  This will then persist for the life of the user and won't be tied just to a session lifetime.  From within a request handler, you can then query this value from the DB as needed.